# Building Truncatable Primes using Nest(List), While, Fold

Tags: performance-tuning, code-review, iteration, functional-style

Here is a video on [Truncatable Primes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=azL5ehbw_24). I tried to build it myself. Here is what I have tried using the method in the video for `left Truncatable Primes`.

```
myNextList[n_] := Select[10^(Length[IntegerDigits[n]])*Range[9] + n, PrimeQ];
SetAttributes[myNextList, Listable];
```

So a bit of testing:

```
myNextList[91]
```

> {191, 491, 691, 991}

```
myNextList[3947]
```

> {}

and

```
myNextList[{13, 23, 43, 53, 73, 83}]
```

> {{113, 313, 613}, {223, 523, 823}, {443, 643, 743}, {353, 653, 853, 953}, {173, 373, 673, 773}, {283, 383, 683, 883, 983}}

Now the goal is to **repeate** the proccess until we get none of them returns a prime. So I tried

```
NestWhileList[myNextList, 7, AllTrue[#, PrimeQ] &]
NestWhile[myNextList, 7, AllTrue[#, PrimeQ] &]
```

> {{317, 617}, {137, 337, 937}, {347, 547, 647, 947}, {167, 367, 467, 967}, {197, 397, 797, 997}}

which should be continued ...

```
myNextList[%]
```

> {{{6317, 8317}, {2617, 3617}}, {{2137, 3137, 9137}, {4337, 6337, 9337}, {4937, 7937}}, {{2347, 3347, 5347}, {3547, 4547, 6547, 7547, 9547}, ...

I think it's an easy fix, with the `test` part, which I have used `AllTrue[#, PrimeQ] &`. But I don't know how to fix it.

If I just use

```
Nest[myNextList, 1, 8]
Nest[myNextList, 7, 8]
Nest[myNextList, 7, 16]
```

for example, it all worked fine. But I want to repeat something from the video and find all 1422 **end points** (as stated in the video at 04:49)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NestGraph` seems like a good choice:

```
ClearAll[myNextList]
myNextList[0] := {2, 3, 5, 7}
myNextList[n_] := Select[10^(Length[IntegerDigits[n]])*Range[9] + n, PrimeQ];


g = NestGraph[myNextList, 0, 10^3];
leaves = Pick[VertexList[g], VertexOutDegree[g], 0];
leaves // Length
```

> 1442

```
Max[leaves]
```

> 357686312646216567629137

Comment: maybe if we add   `myNextList[0]={2,3,5,7};` and start the nesting from `0`
(that is, `g = NestGraph[myNextList,0,10^3]`), then `leaves // Length` gives `1442`. (+1 of course)

Comment: @kglr Yup, that did it. Thank you!

Comment: Related [post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1569707) on the Wolfram Community site.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

**Update 2:** An alternative approach using `FixedPoint`

```
ClearAll[g0, g1, nextDigit]

nextDigit[a__] := Select[Range[9], PrimeQ[FromDigits[{#, a}]] &] /. {} -> {0};

g0[{0, a__}] := {{0, a}}

g0[{0}] := List /@ {2, 3, 5, 7}

g0[{a__}] := {#, a} & /@ nextDigit[a]

g1 = Join @@ g0 /@ # &;

ltprimes3 = FromDigits /@ 
   DeleteCases[SplitBy[Join @@ FixedPoint[g1, {{0}}], # == 0 &], {0}];

Length @ ltprimes3
1442

Max @ ltprimes3
```

> 357686312646216567629137

```
Sort @ ltprimes3 == Sort @ ltprimes2
```

> True

**Update:** To get the list of 1442 primes

```
ClearAll[myNextList2, f0, f1]
myNextList2[n_] := Select[10^(Length[IntegerDigits[n]])*Range[9] + n, PrimeQ] /. {} -> {""};
myNextList2[0] = {2, 3, 5, 7};
myNextList2[""] = Sequence[];

f0[Except[_List]] := Sequence[]
f0[{a___, ""}] := {a, ""}
f0[{a___, b_}] := {a, b, #} & /@ myNextList2[b]

f1 = Join @@ f0 /@ # &;

ltprimes2 = Cases[Join @@ FixedPointList[f1, {{0}}],  {0, ___, x_, ""} :> x];

ltprimes2 // Sort // Short
```

> {2, 5, 773, <<1436>>, 95918918997653319693967, 96686312646216567629137, 357686312646216567629137}

```
Max @ ltprimes2
```

> 357686312646216567629137

```
Length @ ltprimes2
```

> 1442

**Original answer:**

You can use [`FixedPointList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPointList.html):

```
ltprimes = Join @@ FixedPointList[Composition[Flatten, myNextList], {2, 3, 5, 7}];

Length @ ltprimes
```

> 4260

```
Last @ ltprimes
```

> 357686312646216567629137

```
IntegerLength @ Last @ ltprimes
```

> 24

```
Count[FixedPoint[myNextList, {2, 3, 5, 7}], {}, {0, Infinity}]
```

> 1442

Comment: Seemed like my initial code `myNextList` isn't good after all as it can not get the whole list of 1442 numbers. I thought about using `FixedPointList` but then got a bit confused. Thanks.